# How to dynamically decide what tables to join in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table `tbl_Info`:

```
InfoId
Text
PrivacyTypeId
UserName
TypeId
IsInfo
InfoItemId
```

Example of data:

```
1|Some text...|1|userX|1|False|NULL
2|New job created|1|system|3|True|765
3|Image commented|1|system|4|True|457
```

In my application I get all values from this table and I display them as a list.

Application users can click on each of this items and they should be redirected somewhere in application.

I have a few tables in database that is bound for this table but this connection is very dynamic. For example this tables:

```
tbl_Jobs{JobId, Title etc.}, tbl_Articles{ArticleId, Title etc.}
```

**Here is the problem:**
Before I added `IsInfo` and `InfoItemId` I have only one type where users enter this infos and all I need is to get info columns + user full name:

```
select i.*, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as Author 
from tbl_Info i 
left join tbl_Profiles p on i.UserName = p.UserName
where i.PrivacyTypeId = 1
```

Now I need to change this `Author` column with name of `Title` and this values should be: Full name or Job Title or Article Title etc.

I don't know is it possible to make select procedure so it can based on `IsInfo` and `TypeId` get item title from another table with ID of `InfoItemId`.

So something like: If IsInfo = True. Get typeId. And based on this typeId join to some table and get some column from it.

```
IF typeId = 2 ... join tbl_Jobs on ...
IF typeId = 3 ... join tbl_Articles on ...
```

I'm sorry for a little longer post. But I can't find solution for this and I need to explain problem in a little more detail.

Comment: Why are you prefixing everything with `tbl_`?  Everything certainly is a table, so prefixing it is useless noise.   It also allows for better maintanence (if the DBAs decide to replace one of the tables with a view over new tables, say).  All I should need to know is that if I ask for a given data-structure, it responds with a set of data in the proper format - I shouldn't need to care how the data-structure is setup.

Comment: I worked in a company where this was naming convention. It was in my blood for 2 years. But you are right it's not late to change it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
 CASE typeID
   WHEN 1 THEN tbl_Profiles.FirstName + ' ' + tbl_Profiles.LastName
   WHEN 2 THEN ...
   WHEN 3 THEN ...
 END AS Title
FROM tbl_Info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Profiles ON 
   tbl_Info.UserName = tbl_Profiles.UserName
   AND typeID = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Jobs ON
   ....
   AND typeID = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Articles ON
   ....
   AND typeID = 3
```

Comment: I just can't express my thanks for this piece of code :) This solve my issue here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that I have missed something however on first inspection it would appear that you could address your need to have two code paths within a given stored procedure by using a simple IF statement.

```
IF (ConditionIsTrue)
BEGIN
      -- First form of select statement
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     -- Second form of select statement
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to display the data in one big list, you can use an union to tie them together:

```
SELECT i.*, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as Author 
  FROM tbl_Info i
    INNER JOIN tbl_Profiles p ON i.UserName = p.UserName
    WHERE i.PrivacyTypeID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT i.*, j.Title
  FROM tbl_Info i
     INNER JOIN tbl_Jobs j ON ...
     WHERE i.PrivacyTypeID=2
...
```

Otherwise, if you really just want to display different things at a time (i.e. just profiles, just jobs, etc, then go with John Sansom's answer, wrapping it with IF statements